# C# instanitate an object best way?

Tags: c#

The language I use is C#

Say that we want to instantiate an object of type `T` and then set it equal to another object of the same type.

This could be done, as I think, with two ways:

```
T a = new T();
a=b;
```

or

```
T a = b;
```

Which is the better way between these two ways? I think that under the hood, in the second way, the compiler instantiate the object as in the first way, with the new operator - I think that's the only way to do this. Subsequenlty, it sets the `a` equals to `b`

Should we use the first or the second approach and why?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is T suposed to be a value type or reference type?

Comment: @nvoigt is a reference type

Comment: Do you have a C++ background? Assigning a ref type copies the reference in C#, not the object.

Comment: Your assumption about the second method is wrong, `a` will get the same reference as `b`. They will both point to the same memory location essentially.

Comment: @DGibbs: negative.  a will contain the same reference as b, but a will not *get a reference to b*

Comment: @DGibbs, yes you are right, a will get a reference to b, which points to an address in the managed heap, when we are talking about reference types like in my case. So they both will point in the same memory in the managed heap. So why it is wrong?

Comment: @Dan-o Yeah, messed up my wording but my intent was still clear. `They will both point to the same memory location essentially.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiation is a creation of new object. Place where memory for new object would be allocated depends on type of `T`. If `T` is a reference type (i.e. class, see links below), then new data will be allocated on the heap. If `T` is a value type (i.e. int, booleand or other struct), then memory will be allocated on stack. That what `new T()` does.

Next you need to understand what variable `a` holds. If `T` is a reference type, then it will hold reference, i.e. address in memory where your new object is allocated. If `T` is value type, then variable will contain new object itself instead of object's address.

So, `T a = new T()` allocates new object in memory and assigns it's address or value to variable `a`.

If you'll assign new value to variable `a = b`, it will point to new address in memory (where `b` points), or it will contain copy of `b` object data (if it's value type)

So, *conclusion*: if you need to make variable `a` point on some other object or hold it's data, then don't instantiate new object - simply declare variable and assign existing value to it:

```
T a = b;
```

Usefull reading: [Value and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Type Fundamentals by Jeffrey Richter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx)

Comment: thanks! I do know that they hold references. So setting equal a to b they both point to the same address in memory.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios exactly, when you dealing with reference types. If `T` is a value type (e.g. integer, boolean, or other struct) then variable holds real data instead of reference to data

Comment: @ChristosPaisios thanks for accepting, but I've improved my answer, and I believe it will be more clear for you now

Comment: thanks for your effort to expalin me something silly for your level of expertise. Sometimes I wonder how people with not too significant experience downvote questions and asnwers, without be experts. Comments like flup, I think that's offensive and they do not point to developers with lesser experience how to become better. Unfortunately, it makes you believe that once you will get some experience you should become arrogant. Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: @downvoter can you add some comments for me to understand what I missed?

Answer (score 1):

What you are really doing here is storing object references.

So `T a = new T();` will instantiate a new instance of the T class and store its reference (pointer) in your `a` variable.

`T a = b;` will make `a` store the same `object reference` as `b`.

Also, if you want to know what the compiler thinks about all this, code it up and take a look at it using `IlDasm` or `Redgate Reflector`

Answer (score -1):

In the first example you first instantiate a new object of type T and assign it to the variable called `a`. Then you rewrite the reference with the `b`.

In the second example you only assign some existing variable `b` to the variable.

These are not equivalent...

The second approach makes more sense in this specific situation. The first one should be considered only as a means of making sure that the variable `a` contains some default value if something later goes wrong (for instance the creation of the object `b`).

Comment: If he was "your friend" you wouldn't be so rude.

Comment: There was a day where all of us did not know this either.

Comment: @WillDean, rude? Can you show me a single rude part?? Wow, downvoting correct answers for being honest, cause you don't like the exact wording...

Comment: @usr, yes, that was the day when we made our best to study as much as possible... Not roaming through sites like this and asking the most basic questions. Since when does SO promote laziness?

Comment: @DGibbs, because I had one sentence "You don't have a clue my friend, do you?" and obviously people just raged over it...

Comment: @walther I think Stack Overflow needs a quicker way to remove low quality questions. Till then I'll stick to what we have: close because of missing minimal knowledge.

Comment: @walther: I consider "You don't have a clue my friend, do you?" (now removed by a 3rd party) to be rude, I'd be pleased if Stackoverflow wasn't full of rudeness, and down-voting objectionable stuff is, to my mind, a legitimate response.  If you avoid abuse in your answers, they're less likely to get down-voted.  (I've removed my down-vote now, BTW)